# How would I run a python script within a jar file

Tags: java, python

I really need help with this, I’ve been struggling for so long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call python script form java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334494/how-to-call-python-script-form-java-class), specifically look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not much details to go on here. You can consider using [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) to run Python code in a Java application.